# Send hidden input with files in the same forms PHP

Tags: php, post

I want to send a hidden input data with a files in same form to a php script, but the problem is for some reason I cannot read the hidden data it's reading nothing:

```
<form id="C2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='/phps/upload_file.php'>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="C2" />
Profile picute <input type="file" name="photo01" /><br>
    Pic 2 <input type="file" name="photo02" /><br>
    Pic 3 <input type="file" name="photo03" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
    </form>
```

The upload_file.php begining looks like this:

```
require_once('login.php');

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $ID= $_REQUEST['ID'];

    error_log("File ID:".$ID."\n\n"); // I see nothing in the log file

//*****Connect to SQL********

    $db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
        if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MYSQL:" .mysqli_error());

    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database)
        or die("Unable to select database:" . mysqli_error());

    $query = "SELECT current_pn,pic_path FROM partnum WHERE PNID = " . '$ID';
    $queried = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($queried);
```

When I check the log file I see nothing. Anyone has idea why?

Thanks,
Zsolt

Comment: $ID= $_REQUEST['ID'];
Try
$ID= $_POST['ID'];

Comment: If it's `Post` why not using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST?
Second , use `var_dump($ID)` instead of that `error_log` function just to check if there's an error with your function.

Comment: Yeah I only tried this $_Request, beacuse I see somwhere on the internet, but oficially I used $ID= $_POST['ID'];, but didnt work too

Comment: `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` should work, soo problem is not here.

Comment: Try renaming your hidden form field name to `id_photo`, see if that helps. I've seen stranger things happen when using `ID` as a variable.

Comment: @Zsoca Or try `if(isset($_POST['ID'])` instead of `if(isset($_POST)` I think that could work.

Comment: i suggest replacing `error_log("File ID:".$ID."\n\n");` with `print_r($_POST);` just to check if value is passed to your script

Comment: Now I changed the variable name from ID to id_photo and it's working thanks.

Comment: lol, then you pasted the wrong HTML into question... Like @FaceOfJock said, `print_r($_POST);` will show you everything....

Comment: @Zsoca Great and you're welcome I will put it as an answer then.

Comment: @Zsoca If my answer was indeed the actual problem with the issue you were having, then accept it as an answer. Otherwise, I suggest you ask everyone who gave you an answer to delete it, including mine so that you can delete your question afterwards. This is only fair for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Now I changed the variable name from ID to id_photo and it's working thanks."*

As per my original comment:

*"Try renaming your hidden form field name to `id_photo`, see if that helps. "*

The use of `ID` as a variable is not a suggested value to use, because it could cause a conflict somewhere else, in a DB for instance.

### EDIT

After going over the OP's code, the following code should have been used:

`if(isset($_POST['ID'])` instead of `if(isset($_POST)` since `$_POST` is an autoglobal and is always set.

It needs to check whether a value has been set and not a global POST value or as Glavić suggested in the [answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18534941/1415724).

Comment: Stranger things like what?

Comment: @Glavić Just....... strange things happen when using the word `ID`. PHP forms use ID to identify elements, and that could be at play in conjunction with DB's.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `ID` as form input name. Problem here is, that OP has pasted the wrong HTML; because if you copy his example, it will work...

Comment: @Glavić Questions like these that change **"mid-stream"**, tend to go sour and leave room for confusion. It has though happened in the past where someone had a problem when using `ID` as a variable, that is why I suggested to the OP to change it to something else.

Comment: I totally agree with you, that such well known keywords shouldn't be used for form input names, database table fields, etc. Problem here is that, when other people, with same problem come here for solution, they will find this mess ;( But ok, let's not chat here, IMO this question is waste of SO space and should be deleted ;-)

Comment: @Glavić And I agree with you as well, on all points you've outlined above. However the OP won't be able to delete the question because there are already answers given. The OP would either have to put in a special request, or contact everyone who gave an answer, to delete them. It's out of my hands.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo $_POST['ID'];die; and remove rest of the below codes and check are you able to get the value there, if so then the problem is in your rest of the codes. try to enable your error reporting so that you can easily check whats the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Show us what data you have in POST, and you will find your problem.

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    var_dump($_POST);
```

p.s. `isset($_POST)` doesn't make sense since variable $_POST is always set, so simple `if ($_POST) {` is enough.